# Asp.net MVC post list of list entities to a form 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, post

I know a way to post a List to a form, the link for a reference is http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

I have a scenario where i need to post List>, by using the code as mentioned in the above link i got the values in the post.

The html generated is as follows:

```
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[0][0].Quantity" required="required" value="30" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[1][0].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[2][0].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">

<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[0][1].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[1][1].Quantity" required="required" value="50" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[2][1].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
```

My Post action is like

public ActionResult Save(List posItems)

This works well when both the list have same number of items or you can say both List having same count.

When the count in the second list is more than the first list, then i don't get the additional values from the second list.

See the below example where the second list has 1 item more than the first list.

```
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[0][0].Quantity" required="required" value="30" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[1][0].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[2][0].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">

<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[0][1].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[1][1].Quantity" required="required" value="50" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[2][1].Quantity" required="required" value="20" type="text">
<input class="input-micro valid" min="1" name="posItems[3][1].Quantity" required="required" value="114" type="text">
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, is there a way so that i get all the items in the post action?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a two-dimensional array.  In order to have an item 1 in a two-dimensional array, you must have an item 0.  Since you have no [3][0] there can't be a 3[1].  That's just how arrays work and you can't change that.

Your only choice a) not use a multi-dimensional array or b) create a [3][0]

Comment: If i don't use multi-dimensional array, how will i get the list of objects in a post?
I thought there may be a work around for this

Comment: @DeveshTipe - You could create a custom model binder, but it's unclear to me how you would plan to not have a [3][0] in your target array, as C# would not allow that.

Comment: The items are added on the front-end. User has the ability to add/remove items. So the list is not static.
I do have a Custom model binder, but don't know how to get these values

Comment: Even on the model binder i am not getting those values

Answer (score 0):

cshtml:

```
<ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="Items[0].Name" /></li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[0].SubItems[0].Name" /></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[0].SubItems[1].Name" /></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[0].SubItems[2].Name" /></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="Items[1].Name" /></li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[1].SubItems[0].Name" /></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[1].SubItems[1].Name" /></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Items[1].SubItems[2].Name" /></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you at least explain a little?

Comment: This answer needs some explination